# Gap between image and content keeps increasing with background size contain

Tags: css

```
.header-img {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
}
```

As I decrease the size of the browser window the image scales and gap between the image and the content keeps increasing.
I need to solve this and I need to keep the background size to contain.

```
<div class="header-img">
</div>

<div class="content">
sddsfsdfsdfdsfdsf
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dz47c1qn/

Comment: i'd recommend not setting a fixed height for this unless you're going to crop the background image. You may want to look into CSS media queries to scale the div size, or just link the picture instead and float content over it with absolute positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover` if you want your image to keep the original `height`

```css
.header-img {
 background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-img">
</div>

<div class="content">
sddsfsdfsdfdsfdsf
</div>
```

Comment: background-size: cover; makes image not responsive

Comment: cover will keep your div height and resize your background when your screen width changes. On small width you background will be left top and if your screen is too large background image will cover your container. If your want your background to always be center you can add `background-position: center`

Comment: when you use `contain` your container keeps the same height but your background doesn't. this happens because the background image is resized to make sure the image is fully visible